# PgAdmin column naming query syntax beginner problem

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm struggling with writing even simple queries in PgAdmin. I've tried to solve this problem for a while now but am unable to learn why pgAdmin behaves like it does:

I'm trying to run a very simple query:

`SELECT * FROM public."Sync" WHERE organizationId = "xxx";`

For this query I'm seing the following error message:

> ERROR:  column "organizationid" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT * FROM
> public."Sync" WHERE organizationId = "cljybe6z...
> ^ HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "Sync.organizationId".

It seems the casing of "organizationId" is not respected in this instance. Butting in in quotes, however, does not help as well.

Writing "Sync.organizationId" produces an error as well.

There are several things I don't understand here:
1.) How to reference the column correctly?
2.) Why do I have to specify the table along with the schema `public."Sync"` and can't just write sync as I can in `psql`?

I know this might be a beginner question but I'm really stuck on this for a long time.

Comment: "*How to reference the column correctly?*" - we can't tell unless you show us how the table was created and how the column is defined. Please post the SQL shown in the "SQL" tab when you inspect the table in pgadmin.

Comment: "*Why do I have to specify the table along with the schema?*" - you don't have to. Writing just `sync` (or possibly `"Sync"`, if you defined the name with an actual capital letter) will work.

Comment: You don't have to specify public."Sync". It could just be "Sync". Check your table definition. If the column name is in quotes then casing is respected and you need to write with quotes as well. Otherwise you could directly write organizationid.

Comment: I think my entire issue was around the fact that I did not understand the quotation rules in postgres. I forgot to wrap the literal value in single quotes and the column name in double quotes. Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: Oh I totally missed that you wrote the string literal with double quotes. It is not specific to postgreSQL, other SQL databases behave same as well. Double quotes for identifiers (if needed) and single quotes for string literals.

Comment: Read [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some basic rules to understand how PostgreSQL handles names and content:

- All names will be lower case by default
- Unless you create an object name using double quotes " around it
- Avoid double quotes " like the plague
- Content must be within single quotes '
- Unless you use dollar quoting for you content, like $$ or $xx$

Now your query:
SELECT * FROM public."Sync" WHERE organizationId = "xxx";

My personal comment about this one:

- The table Sync should never ever have been created in upper case, using double quotes
- Now you shot yourself in the foot, you must always use double quotes around this object name
- I would alter the table name to lower case to get rid of the need for double quotes everywhere
- xxx is content, and must be between single quotes 'xxx'
- I would not advice the usage of dollar quoting, only for rare exceptions